# Can I interpret doc2vec components?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, doc2vec, lightgbm

I am solving a binary text classification problem with corporate filings. Using Doc2Vec embeddings of length 100 with LightGBM is producing great results. However, for this project it would be very valuable to approximate a thematic meaning for at least one of the components. Ideally, this would be a feature ranked with high importance by LightGBM explained anecdotally with a few examples.

Has anyone attempted this, or should interpretation be off the table for a high-dimensional model with this level of complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The individual dimensions of a `Doc2Vec` representation should not be considered independent, interpretable features. They're only useful in concert with each other, and the exact directions aligned with individual coordinate-axes may not be strongly meaningful in any human-describable sense.

However, *neighborhoods* of the space may loosely fit describable themes, and certain *directions* (not specifically parallel with coordinate-axes) may loosely fit semantic themes.

But to characterize those, you might try to find the centroid points of groups-of-related-documents, or discovered clusters, and compare the relative distances/directions between those centroids.